# In which function/class is the dbprefix added to the table name in Codeigniter Active Record requests?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

**In which function/class is the dbprefix added to the table name in Codeigniter Active Record requests?**

I need to dynamically change the prefix based on the table name but cannot find the function which prepends the prefix in the first place.

DB_active_rec.php has a dbprefix() function but this appears to have no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the driver you're using, and it's probably in a few places in that driver too.

Try the DB_active_rec.php file's `set_dbprefix()` method to override it.  This will get very messy (keeping track of which table you're querying), and I would recommend changing your schema instead.

Answer (score 2):

A line taken from the codeigniter [site](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html)

```
$this->db->set_dbprefix('newprefix');
```

Answer (score 1):

In application/config/database.php you can set a prefix variable. Anytime you use Active Records, the prefix is added.